# Search for column name in multiple databases on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I need to find specific columns in many databases, located on the same SQL Server 2008. I have tried many solutions over the internet, but none worked for more than system databases. What is the best way to extend the search to look inside all databases on one server?

Comment: @Hogan You must be still sleep, you can have multiple database in one server

Comment: Have you looked into [Redgate's SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)?

Comment: Can you show some code that gets close and maybe we can fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

This solution uses the SP `sp_MSforeachdb`. This SP allows you, to use the same statement for alle existing databases. The Questionmark stand as place holder for the actual database name.

As we need to get the result in one single table I declare one first and use `INSERT INTO SomeTable EXEC SomeSP`-syntax to insert the result(s) of a SP into a fitting table (-variable):

**Attention** This SP is known for skipping some tables. [Here's a thread to read more about this (including a solution for one special case)](https://serverfault.com/q/162656).

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)='SomeColumnName';

DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX)='USE [?]; SELECT TABLE_CATALOG
                                              ,TABLE_SCHEMA
                                              ,TABLE_NAME
                                              ,COLUMN_NAME 
                                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                        WHERE COLUMN_NAME=''' + @ColumnName + ''';';     

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
                   TABLE_CATALOG VARCHAR(100)
                  ,TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(100)
                  ,TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)
                  ,COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100)
                  );

INSERT INTO @tbl
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb @Command

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

### UPDATE Another approach without sp_MSforeachdb

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)='SomeColumnName';

DECLARE @Template VARCHAR(MAX)='USE ***; SELECT TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME=''' + @ColumnName + ''';';  

DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT REPLACE(@Template,'***', QUOTENAME(name))
    FROM sys.databases
    FOR XML PATH('')
);

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
                   TABLE_CATALOG VARCHAR(100)
                  ,TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(100)
                  ,TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100)
                  ,COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100)
                  );

INSERT INTO @tbl
EXEC (@Command);

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Comment: I personally don't like the sp_MSforeachdb because it skips databases. And I don't like using INFORMATION_SCHEMA (especially to find schema), since according to MS it isn't reliable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx Here is a great article from Aaron Bertrand about skipping databases and a great solution. https://sqlblog.org/2018/10/22/sp-ineachdb-2

Comment: @Alcors Hi, I just added another approach without using this querky sp...

Comment: @SeanLange I had no idea this was an issue. I've never witnessed it, but it does make one question gravity now.

Comment: @SeanLange Hi I just edited my answer and added a new approach without this sp

Comment: Once again you posted a solution before I was able to finish typing up one myself. Well done sir!!!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti is that an anvil floating next to you? LOL.