# SQL Server: Find All Columns Across Multiple Databases Where a Substring Is Present

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working with a SQL Server that has multiple databases in its schema (let's call them alpha, beta, gamma, etc.).

I'm looking to go through each of these databases and find which columns have at least one value containing a certain substring (let's say it is "dog").

I know that if I want to check if a certain column (COLUMN_NAME) contains this substring I could use

```
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%dog%'
```

and if the table that is returned is not empty, that column had the sub string and if the table is empty, there was no substring "dog."

For a more concrete example, let's say I have the table:

| Person | Pet | Favorite Animal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Cat | Dog |
| James | Dog | Lion |

I would want the result of my query to be (in some format) "Pet" and "Favorite Animal."

What I don't know is how to iterate over all of the columns (check if any values of each column has "dog"), let alone all of the columns of all of the databases.

How would I do this? Is this beyond the scope of a SQL query (in other words, should this be done in something like Python)?

(Edited for clarity of question.)

Comment: Take a look at this post it should get you closer [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231491/search-for-column-name-in-multiple-databases-on-sql-server)

Comment: Schemas don't contain databases, databases contain schemas. Do you have multiple databases or multiple schemas? You need some kind of dynamic SQL, but it's unclear what you have.

Comment: Try simple searching using "sql server search all columns for string" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not sure the terminology, but I have multiple databases in the sense that I have to use a USE statement when I make queries

Comment: Are you searching for columns with the string in the name or are you trying to look through all columns in every table where the value in the rows is like your string?

Comment: Can you just query sys.columns  for each database? https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @SeanLange I've edited my question to better explain what I'm looking to do. I think what I'm confused about is along the lines of your second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it with pure t-sql. It involves cursors and dynamic sql wich is best avoided if possible. First loop through all databases and get the columns of type varchar/nvarchar (you can add other types if you want like text/ntext). Then loop through all columns using dynamic sql to count rows that have a match.

**Warning**: Do not run this query on a big production environment as it can have serious impact on performance.

```
--Set the search query
DECLARE @search_query NVARCHAR(200) = '%dog%';

--Create temp output table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #columns;
CREATE TABLE #columns (
    _database_name NVARCHAR(4000),
    _schema_name NVARCHAR(4000),
    _table_name NVARCHAR(4000),
    _column_name NVARCHAR(4000),
    _count INT
);

/*
    1. Loop through all databases on server
    and get columns of type nvarchar och varchar
*/

DECLARE @database_name NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Create a cursor for database names except
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    [name]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE
    --Modify this to exclude other databases
    name NOT IN ('SSISDB','master','tempdb','model','msdb');

OPEN database_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @database_name;

-- Loop through the databases and insert columns in temp-table
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    SET @sql = CONCAT(
        '
        INSERT INTO #columns (_database_name,_schema_name,_table_name,_column_name)
        SELECT ''',
            @database_name,''' database_name,
            s.name schema_name,
            t.name table_name,
            c.name column_name
        FROM [',@database_name,'].sys.all_objects t
        JOIN [',@database_name,'].sys.schemas s
        ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        JOIN [',@database_name,'].sys.all_columns c
        ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        JOIN [',@database_name,'].sys.types ty
        ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
        WHERE 
            ty.name IN (''nvarchar'',''varchar'') AND
            is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
            t.type = ''U''');

    EXEC (@sql);
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @database_name;
END

CLOSE database_cursor;
DEALLOCATE database_cursor;

/* 
    Step 2: Loop through the columns of all 
    databases, count ocurrences of the query
    and add to temp table
*/
DECLARE @column_name NVARCHAR(4000),@table_name NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
CONCAT('[',_column_name,']'),
CONCAT('[',_database_name,'].[',_schema_name,'].[',_table_name,']')
FROM #columns

OPEN column_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @column_name, @table_name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

    SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE columns
    SET _count = row_search._count  
    FROM #columns columns
    JOIN (
    SELECT
    COUNT(*) _count
    FROM ',@table_name,'
    WHERE ',@column_name,' LIKE ''',@search_query,'''
    ) row_search ON 1=1
    WHERE 
        CONCAT(''['',_database_name,''].['',_schema_name,''].['',_table_name,'']'') = ''',@table_name,''' AND
        CONCAT(''['',_column_name,'']'') = ''',@column_name,''''
    )   
    ;
    EXEC (@sql);
FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @column_name,@table_name;
END

CLOSE column_cursor;
DEALLOCATE column_cursor;

;
--Final output
SELECT 
    _database_name [Database],
    _schema_name [Schema],
    _table_name [Table],
    _column_name [Column],
    _count [Count]
FROM #columns
```

Comment: I may have worded the question confusingly. I want to check not if the column name itself contains the substring, but if one of its values does. In other words, if I used a LIKE statement on each column for the substring "dog", would the table that is returned be empty or have rows. Any insight on how this could be done iteratively?

Comment: @reisnern21, See my now modified answer.